# Duplicate record inserted into SQL Server table using stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have implemented a procedure where I passed user made unique id for every record insert. But the problem is when at the same time multiple hits occurs unique id is allotted to all users.

My procedure code is

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[name]
    (
     --@reg_id int,
     @name nvarchar(50),    
     @designation int,
     @deptmntid int,
     --@officeid int,
     @disid int,
     @bentype_id int,
     @benificry_type nvarchar(50),
     @dob datetime,
     @basic_pay int,
     @home_address nvarchar(200),
     @mobile nvarchar(50),
     @email nvarchar(50),
     @aadhar nvarchar(50),
     @applicant_image image,
     @ip nvarchar(50),
     @udate datetime,
     @ddoid int,
     @depend_id int,
     @relation int,
     @flag int,
     @officename nvarchar(max),
     @deptother nvarchar(max),
     @desigother nvarchar(max),
     @regno bigint output,
     @flg int output)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @regnc char(6);
    DECLARE @numm varchar(7);
    DECLARE @regnc_dcd varchar(11);
    DECLARE @final_appno varchar(11);
    DECLARE @bentype int;
    DECLARE @ddotocode int;
    DECLARE @ddochk int;
    DECLARE @regidchk bigint;   

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        SELECT @ddochk = ddoid 
        FROM tablename 
        WHERE ddoid = @ddoid;

        IF (@ddochk IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @numm = '1';
            SET @regnc = STUFF(@numm, 1, 0, REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(@numm)));
            SET @regnc_dcd = cast(@ddoid as varchar(4)) + cast(@bentype_id as varchar(1)) + cast(@regnc as varchar(6)); 
            SET @final_appno = @regnc_dcd
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT 
                @numm = MAX(ISNULL(auto_inc, 0) + 1),
                @ddotocode = ddoid 
            FROM 
                tablename 
            WHERE
                ddoid = @ddoid;

            SET @regnc = STUFF(@numm, 1, 0, REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(@numm)));
            SET @regnc_dcd=cast(@ddotocode as varchar(4)) + cast(@bentype_id as varchar(1)) + cast(@regnc as varchar(6)); 
            SET @final_appno = @regnc_dcd
        END

        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tablename (reg_id, auto_inc, name, desigid, deptid, distid, bentype_id, benificry_type, dob, basic_pay, home_address, mobile, email, aadhar, ip, udate, ddoid, applicant_image, flag, officename, deptother, desigother) 
            VALUES (@final_appno, @regnc, @name, @designation, @deptmntid, @disid, @bentype_id, @benificry_type, @dob, @basic_pay, @home_address, @mobile, @email, @aadhar, @ip, @udate, @ddoid, @applicant_image, @flag, @officename, @deptother, @desigother)

            SET @regno = @final_appno;
        END

        IF @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK
            -- Raise an error and return
            RAISERROR ('Error in Inserting record from temp.....', 16, 1)
            RETURN
        END

        BEGIN   
            INSERT INTO SHCbeneficiary(card_id, depend_id, pic, name, dob, relation, ip, aadhar, udate) 
            VALUES (@final_appno, @depend_id, @applicant_image, @name, @dob, @relation, @ip, @aadhar, @udate)

            IF @@ERROR <> 0
            BEGIN
               -- Rollback the transaction
               ROLLBACK

               -- Raise an error and return
               RAISERROR ('Error in updating record in persoaldetails....!!!', 16, 1)
               RETURN
            END

            SET @flg = 1;
        END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I want to check duplicate data until a unique id is not found in table.
It means I want to use recursion in procedure.

Also I have used a CTEs, scalar-valued function for the uniqueness but it's not working well. Please help

Comment: What version of SQL Server is this?

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use an IDENTITY column?

Comment: if i use identity then i can't move my data from one table to another.

Comment: and also if i use identity then in database crash condition how i will allot the same number as previous alloted to every rows

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or newer you can use `SEQUENCES`, a new user-defined object that generates a sequence of numbers. Example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.MySequence
    AS int
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1;
```

You can retrieve the sequential values with a query, like so:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.MySequence AS [Value];
```

Here is the tech article for more information:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058(v=sql.110).aspx